# Allure error messages Could not update step: no step running o.qameta.allure.AllureLifecycle - Could not stop step: no step running

Tags: allure

I use Java and Cucumber 7 and Allure dependencies and Plugin with Allure.  The reports are created but I keep getting theses errors

> ERROR io.qameta.allure.AllureLifecycle - Could not update step: no
> step running

> ERROR io.qameta.allure.AllureLifecycle - Could not stop
> step: no step running

.

I've tried many things based on Google serach results but nothing helps

I don't want above error messages appear in my output log